# How to ignore question mark ? characters when printing html with PHP

Tags: php, html, escaping

I'm printing obfuscated html code with PHP that has a LOT of question marks in it. 
The problem is this is causing PHP parse errors:

Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?'

How would I go about escaping/ignoring them without actually escaping them in the html code?

Ex:

```
<?php if ($print_html) { ?> 

var test = "a;sdkfhals?asdf/?aHluh?/daldj????adfakjsd????????????/asdfj?"; 

<?php } ?>
```

Edit: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0j1fm7p4/1/

changing short_open_tag to Off in my php.ini fixed the problem

Comment: I cannot see a problem with that code. Are you _really_ sure you got the right line where the syntax error is pointed out?

Comment: sounds like an encoding issue to me

Comment: @arkascha yes, I'm positive of the right line, but the actual line is much longer than the one in the example.  actual line:  https://jsfiddle.net/0j1fm7p4/

Comment: Ah, that is something _completely_ different! Most likely you terminate the string `"` somehow, then certainly stränge things may happen. One question: why on earth is obfuscation used? That _always_ causes endless trouble, typically without real benefit...

Comment: @arkascha exact code:  https://jsfiddle.net/0j1fm7p4/1/

Comment: @arkascha I agree about the obfuscation.. but company policy

Comment: Even worse. You work for a company that insists on using obfuscation? Oh dear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current example, this is because `short_open_tag` is `On` in the php.ini config file. Since you have some `<?` in your obfuscated var, you get this error.

Try set it to `Off`

Comment: This worked after changing this in the php.ini and restarting apache. Thank you!